# Problems with pop() using Deque in Java

Tags: java, deque

I've encountered a strange issue using a `Deque`.

I've reformatted my code twice now, and both forms has resulted in the same issue.

Whether i `push()` a `String[]` or an `ArrayList<String>` to the `Deque` (formatted appropriately for one or the other), it `pop()` 's as an Object. I cannot seem to use what so ever.

When i `push()` a `String[]` and then `pop()`, i cannot access indices. When i `push()` an `ArrayList<String>` and then `pop()`, i cannot use `get()` on it.

When i `push()` an element, it then `pop()` 's as something else. It says

> "___ required, but Object found".

I don't understand why, or how i can use `Deque` successfully.

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly cast your the variable returned by `pop()` to its original type e.g. `String[]` or `ArrayList`.

Comment: I thought i tried this, but i must have made some silly mistake. This is embarrassing- but thank you!